# Pandas ignore many rows when reading csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with more than 1,000,000 rows.

However, `read_csv` cannot read them all.

`products = pd.read_csv("PAD_NEW.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", error_bad_lines=False)`

```
products.shape
(859971, 137)
```

But in r using `fread`, i can get 1048575

```
> dim(products)
[1] 1048575     137
```

I tried to read using R first then write a new file for Python. But it did not work.

UPDATE: I manually check those rows being ignored, there is a column named `description` and there are sentences like "new product, next week" I think python take the "," in this column as a separate. Because after I delete this column it works.

Comment: pandas skips newlines by default. Do you have any of those? What does adding `skip_blank_lines=False` do?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ No, I manually checked some rows and they had values. I just updated the question.

Comment: Note that `1048575 = 2^20-1` so there is likely some truncation going on somewhere.